# Ubuntu でログインしたときに、 update 可能だと表示されるパッケージを update するには？

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu にログインした際に、もろもろのログインメッセージの中に、次のような文章が含まれていました。

```
9 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.
```

`sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade` を実行しましたが、特にパッケージが更新された様子はなく、
実際、ログインしなおすと再度上記のメッセージが表示されました。

質問:

これら (おそらくあるであろう) パッケージのアップデートは、どうやったら実行できますか？

環境:

ubuntu 14.04@vagrant,
ssh した際に上記メッセージが表示。

Comment: パッケージ構成に影響が出るのでアップデートされているパッケージ内容を要確認かと思いますが、`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`はどうでしょうか？`sudo apt-get upgrade`は構成に影響のない範囲でアップグレードするのでカーネル含んだアップデートだと構成変更できずアップデートできないような？

Comment: Ubuntuのバージョンやログイン方法について具体的に記述すると正確な回答が得られるかもしれませんが、次の情報は役に立つでしょうか。
曰く、キャッシュされた情報が使用されるため正確では無い場合があり、設定で挙動変更可能である、と。
[Why is the available updates data always stale after upgrading to 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/778754/why-is-the-available-updates-data-always-stale-after-upgrading-to-14-04/785258#785258)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` で、"System restart required " と表示されたので、再起動した後はひとまず表示されなくなりました。